# Need to capture and store a Linear Reference/Engineering Stationing number in SQLite Database in Android Application

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Looking for any suggestions for storing a Linear Reference/Engineering Stationing number in SQLite with the Android App I am making. I plan on capturing it with an EditText but do not know really how to accomplish it with the '+' character embedded into the number value. Example: Engineering Station 1145+86 on pipeline Alpha = 114,586 feet (from the [Linear referencing-wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_referencing)). Also since this value has the potential to be measured in tenths and possibly hundredths, the Example number could very well be 1145+86.34 so I need to store it as a double I am thinking as well. Are there any Java libs that would make this process easier that anyone could recommend? Also, since I am going to have to deal with the '+' character, would storing the value as a String or Blob in SQLite be better? Thank you for any insight or suggestions.

Comment: I recommend you use the realm library because it is often faster than SQLite. And it is better to store the value as String. Here's a link: https://realm.io

Comment: @ Rosario Pereira Fernandes for the suggestion. I want to be able to export this database file upon completion of collecting data and use with SQLite Applications or CSV. Can Realm database be exported to other formats?

Comment: Not really. In order to export this, you'd have to use another library like OpenCSV.

Comment: @ Rosario Pereira Fernandes. Thanks for the info nevertheless. I briefly looked at Realm once before but will revisit it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a reference consists of two numbers, the base reference and the offset, so you should store it in two numeric columns. (How the data is stored is a different question from how it is formatted to be displayed to the user.)

If the reference marker ("1145" in this example) is not identified by its own position but by something else (such as a name), you would need to store it as a string.

Comment: This is a great idea that I've not thought about. Thank you and I will look into implementing this as you've suggested. I have accepted your answer. Thanks for the help and suggestion.